# Command line options

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am confused about Ruby command-line options. Both `-C dir` and `-X dir` remove directory, but how do they differ from each other?

- How does `-x [dir]` differ from `-X dir`?
- What does `-I dir` do (I know that it adds `dir` as the directory for loading libraries)?

Comment: So basically there are no difference between `-C dir and -X dir`. Am i correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's create a test.rb file in home directory with following:

```
hello
#!/usr/bin/ruby
p "here"
```

Now if we try to run it:

```
ruby -C /home/my_home test.rb
```

Which means change working directory to /home/my_home and run test.rb you will get an error:

```
test.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object (NameError)
```

If we run it with:

```
ruby -x /home/my_home test.rb
```

We will get "here" printed and get no error. The **main** difference between -x and -C is that -x removes everything before the `#!/usr/bin/ruby` line. And you don't have to set directory to cd too, when using -x. Because the main purpose of -x is to remove lines and it just includes -C functionality too, if needed.

```
cd /home/my_home; ruby -x test.rb
```

See (ruby --help)

- -Cdirectory     *cd to directory, before executing your script*
- -x[directory]   *strip off text before #!ruby line and perhaps cd to directory*

As for -I. You can provide the directories that ruby will search for the file you execute or require.

```
ruby -x test.rb
```

Ruby will not find the test.rb file unless you are in /home/my_home. But if you add -I ruby will look for test.rb in "/home/my_home" too.

```
ruby -x -I/home/my_home test.rb
```

The difference with -C is that it will not change directory before executing, but will just search for files there.

Comment: he he ! Okay `SO` is too clever to hide the `WHO`. I thought you didn't :-P

Comment: I can't see the answer of the Question `How does -x [dir] differ from -X dir?` . Can you help me where it is in your answer! :) rest all I have understood!

Comment: -C is the same as -X (big X).

Comment: `+1` to you again,just to show your interest being a Ruby programmer to another newbie to `Ruby`. :)

Answer (score 2):

-C and -X options do the same job (Changes directory before executing). There is no difference.

-I option is used for adding path to $LOAD_PATH

For example: Assume you have ruby file called my_print_class.rb in my_lib directory
my_print_class.rb:(~/my_lib/my_print_class.rb)

```
class MyPrintClass
   def self.my_print(str)
     puts str
   end
end
```

Now you have my_call.rb in home(~).

~/my_call.rb:

```
 require 'my_print_class'
 MyPrintClass.my_print("Hello world")
```

For this you need path of my_print_class so you use ruby -I my_lib my_call.rb

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_command_line_options.htm

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from `man ruby` or some docs online, `-C` and `-X` is the same.

And `-I` will add some dir to ruby LOAD_PATH. For example, I have `./a/my.rb` and `./test.rb' like this:

```
# ./a/my.rb
def hello
  puts 'hello from a/my'
end

# ./test.rb
require 'my'
hello
```

And I execute `ruby -I ./a test.rb`. This will print `hello from a/my`. Without `-I`, ruby will report an error: `cannot load such file -- my`, because `./a` is not in current LOAD_PATH.

Comment: I can't see the answer of the Question How does -x [dir] differ from -X dir? . Can you help me where it is in your answer! :) rest all I have understood!